# Android Facebook API publish photo

Tags: android, facebook, api, bitmap, share

I'm completely lost on this Facebook API for Android, BECAUSE THE DOCUMENTATION IS HORRIBLE!!
Even when I copy their examples to the character, (ammending to fit my app) it still doesn't work!

I have attached to my share button:

```
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("meal", "https://example.com/cooking-app/meal/Lamb-Vindaloo.html");
        action.setType("feed");
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (hasIcon) {
            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)recipeIcon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon_special_rosemary);
        }

    List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Log.d("image!", bitmap.getByteCount() + "");
            images.add(bitmap);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "meal")
        .setImageAttachmentsForAction(images, true)
        .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else {
            Log.d("no image", "");
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "meal")
            .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        }
```

This goes through all fine, even the Log tells me the Bitmap is there, is not null, and contains a byteCount of ~160kb, but when I attach it to the share dialog it comes up with this...

```
01-21 00:39:30.214: E/Activity(2214): Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Error retrieving image attachment.
```

What?! Is it not attaching correctly? Well, it mustn't be but this is the example copied direct from their documentation and it doesn't work! I only want to upload the current image. Poor show

Answer (score 0):

Please see the reference docs for the method you're calling - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder/#setImageAttachmentFilesForAction

"In order for the images to be provided to the Facebook application as part of the app call, the NativeAppCallContentProvider must be specified correctly in the application's AndroidManifest.xml."

In NativeappCallContentProvider - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/NativeAppCallContentProvider/ - you'll see that you need to add com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider{FACEBOOK_APP_ID} to your manifest.

Comment: Cheers, but i decided to use the SimpleFacebook API, much much easier. Thanks anyway